# How to increase Ubuntu partition size if my laptop is dual booted with windows 10?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk

My laptop is dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to increase my root and home partition size without reinstalling Ubuntu or windows. I cannot part more than 4 drives in my laptop. My laptop was DOS. How can I increase partitions size for Ubuntu without losing data and re installing. I searched on google and found some software "gparted" but have no idea. Please help me.
I don't want to boot from disk or usb again. I cannot do more partitions as I can only have at most 4 disk partitions :-

Primary partition (System reserved files)

C drive (windows)

Root (Ubuntu)

Home (Ubuntu)

Now what to do ?

Comment: Boot windows and reduce the size of your windows partition from within windows. Then boot a live CD , run gparted and add the unallocated space to your ubuntu partitions.

Comment: But be carefull, starting point of \ partition must be the same. If not, Grub can't find it and you'll not be able to start ubuntu. I don't recomend increase root partition. \Home no problem. Why don't you not reinstall?

Comment: @Tim that's usually overkill.  And you *can* repair grub before you restart, if you do the resizing from a LiveCD you can then run `update-grub` from the LiveCD *before* rebooting, and Grub will have the updated partition layout data.  (Also, reinstalling *just* to resize a partition is a bad practice...)

Comment: @Tim, in this comment and in another post you used `\ ` to denote paths. It should be `/` (for the root directory) and `/home` for the home directory.

Comment: I cannot do more partitions as I can only have at most 4 disk partitions. My laptop was DOS. I don't know why I can't have more than 4 partitions. This problem made it very hard to install Ubuntu first time.